# Proper term for a monotonic magma

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, magma

Let $M$ be the multiplication table for a finite magma. Entries are labeled $0,\ldots,n-1$.

M has the property that $M(i,j)\ge i, M(i,j) \ge j$.

What is the proper term for this kind of magma and could you provide any references?

Monotonic? Convex? I am sure there is a term for this already in the literature.

Comment: Do you mean an associative algebra or a magma?

Comment: Magmas in general. Special terminology for more specific classes of multiplication tables would also be welcome.

Comment: Since your property is not an isomorphism invariant, I doubt that there is a name for it in the algebra literature. I might be wrong.